# WPF ShaderEffect with PS 3.0 shaders

Tags: wpf, effects, shader, wpf-4.0

Where could I find examples of PS 3.0 shaders used as [ShaderEffects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect.aspx) for WPF 4? I'm looking for tutorials, presentations, any resource on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best information you're going to get is that of the MSDN documentation for [the `ShaderEffect` class in WPF 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect(VS.100).aspx). Were you looking for anything more specific?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for "goodies" :D Some impressive stuff that I can throw at it, gotchas, wow-factor gems, tutorials on what's new, in the same sense that there are such articles when it comes to PS 2.0 Shaders.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there still aren't any resources at all on WPF + PS 3.0 (at least after searching 20 minutes on the web).

You'll have to wait or create your own PS 3.0 shaders.

Comment: Well, they'd better show up in six days until the bounty expires :))